# Clarified Bloody Mary and Egg Whites

Tags: cocktails

Does anyone have a good resource for clarifying fruits and veggies and using as a cocktail mixer? I had this fabulous Bloody Mary last weekend. It was was made with yellow tomato and yellow bell pepper. Evidently egg whites remove impurities or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Egg whites](https://winemakermag.com/993-egg-white-fining-overoaking-wine-wizard) are used in wine and other beverages to precipitate the solids. I'm not sure how this would be done for a bloody mary, but in wine you basically whip up some egg whites until foamy then put them in the wine barrel and let setting for for several weeks. Most of the action takes place right away. You can also use [Gelatin](https://winemakermag.com/26-a-clearer-understanding-of-fining-agents) for the same purpose. I use it in my homebrew all the time.